# How to fix FileSystemException thrown by LocalStorage Library in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the Local Storage Library in my Flutter App to store, which I received from the Database. I need to store it, since the User should be able to close the App and go back without the need to actualize the Data. Thats why I decided to use Localstorage.
Also tried Shared Preferences because I already used it in the past, but the Problem is, that this Library only stores small Sets of Data, which doesnt work, because I have to store the hole Object received from the Database.

I am receiving the following Errors when I run the App:

```
E/flutter (23193): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: An async operation is currently pending, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.lieferantenapp/app_flutter/localstorage'
E/flutter (23193):
E/flutter (23193): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (23193): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (23193): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

How can I fix these?
Also, let me know if the way I am storing the Data is okay oder completely stupid and way more easy to do.

Comment: did you able to fix this ?

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil no I wasnt

Comment: you can use [synchronized](https://pub.dev/packages/synchronized) pakage to apply `Lock` on operations.